# Testing defaults in Rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, actionmailer

How are you testing these lines in your ActionMailer specs?

```
default 'HEADER' => Proc.new { "information" },
  :cc => "asdf@asdf.com",
  :from => "asdf@asdf.com",
  :to => "asdf@asdf.com"
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about testing default headers and email fields, I'd check the actionmailer test coverage on those. If you are adding headers, I think there is a headers hash you can check in controller tests, or you can use curl with `--head` and inspect the raw output.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
# notifier_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe Notifier do
  describe "welcome" do
    let(:user) { Factory :user }
    let(:mail) { Notifier.welcome(user) }

    it "renders the headers" do
      mail.content_type.should eq('text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
      mail.subject.should eq("Welcome")
      mail.cc.should eq(["zombie@example.com"])
      mail.from.should eq(["zombie@example.com"])
      mail.to.should eq([user.email])
    end

    it "renders the body" do
      mail.body.encoded.should match("Hi")
    end
  end
end
```

This is how [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test) (= whole buncha people) does it.